# How do I combine shape files

Tags: r, merge, shapefile

I need to create a map of the African continent for a project I'm working on. In order to do that, I have been trying to combine individual country shape files I downloaded from [GADM](https://gadm.org/data.html).

```
africa_continent <- bind(angola, benin, burkina_faso, burundi, cameroon, chad, comoros, congo, democratic_republic_congo, cote_divoire,
                     eswatini, gabon, gambia, ghana, guinea, kenya, liberia, madagascar, malawi,
                     mali, mozambique, namibia, niger, nigeria, rwanda, saotome_principe, senegal, 
                     sierra_leone, tanzania, togo, uganda, zambia, zimbabwe)
africa_continent_sf = st_as_sf(africa_continent)

tm_shape(africa_continent_sf) +
     tm_borders()+
      tm_fill()
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT source_crs_auth_name, source_crs_code, target_crs_auth_name, target_crs_code, cov.auth_name, cov.code, cov.table_name, area.south_lat, area.west_lon, area.north_lat, area.east_lon, ss.replacement_auth_name, ss.replacement_code FROM coordinate_operation_view cov JOIN area ON cov.area_of_use_auth_name = area.auth_name AND cov.area_of_use_code = area.code LEFT JOIN supersession ss ON ss.superseded_table_name = cov.table_name AND ss.superseded_auth_name = cov.auth_name AND ss.superseded_code = cov.code AND ss.superseded_table_name = ss.replacement_table_name WHERE ((source_crs_auth_name = ? AND source_crs_code = ? AND target_crs_auth_name = ? AND target_crs_code = ?) OR (source_crs_auth_name = ? AND source_crs_code = ? AND target_crs_auth_name = ? AND target_crs_code = ?)) AND cov.deprecated = 0 AND cov.auth_name = ? ORDER BY pseudo_area_from_swne(south_lat, west_lon, north_lat, east_lon) DESC, (CASE WHEN accuracy is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), accuracy: no such table: area
Error in CPL_lwgeom_transform(x, crs) : 
  st_lwgeom_transform: one of the proj strings is invalid
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Or if there is some other way to get a shapefile for Africa? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the packages you are using to the code.

Comment: If you see "one of the proj strings is invalid" then you need to find out which one. What does `st_crs(mali)` for example say? Is it a valid projection string? Try combining the first half of those objects to see if you still get the error. Or the first two. Or any random pair. Maybe all your proj strings are invalid. How did you create them and which package does `bind` come from?

Comment: I just downloaded two countries (benin, ghana) from GADM in all the formats (shp, geojson, gpkg, kmz), read them using `sp`, and tried combining using `bind` from the `raster` package. This worked fine. Try `bind(benin, ghana)` and edit your Q to show how you constructed your data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since [GADM](https://gadm.org/data.html) looks to have some stipulations required to access the data, here is how I would go about it with package [{rnaturalearth}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnaturalearth/README.html)

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tmap)    

africa_continent <- ne_countries(continent = 'africa')

tmap_mode('view')

tm_shape(africa_continent) +
  tm_borders()+
  tm_fill()
```

When you check the class of africa_continent with `class(africa_continent)` it is a SpatialPolygonsDataframe.

If you wish to convert to class sf, then use `africa_continent_sf = st_as_sf(africa_continent)` and proceed with your script as below:

```
tm_shape(africa_continent_sf) +
  tm_borders()+
  tm_fill()
```

I am familiar with the error message you're receiving- it may indicate that you're trying to plot more than one geometry type. I would suggest correcting this in your original script with `sf::st_collection_extract()` but as [Susan Switzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11535816/susan-switzer) has suggested, a bit more of a reproducible example is needed to help you with this more directly.